# Error when using MinMaxScaler with some data

Tags: python

I'm trying to use MinMaxScaler to normalize my data. The strange thing is some data works, some do not.

My x data is contains coordinates, has shape (21,24321). Hence, there are 21 rows and 24321 columns, looking like this:

```
array([[-1.72507889, -1.70618793, -1.68895362, ...,  1.68897011,
         1.70620441,  1.72343872],
       [-1.72507889, -1.70618793, -1.68895362, ...,  1.68897011,
         1.70620441,  1.72343872],
       [-1.72507889, -1.70618793, -1.68895362, ...,  1.68897011,
         1.70620441,  1.72343872],
       ...,
       [-1.72507889, -1.70618793, -1.68895362, ...,  1.68897011,
         1.70620441,  1.72343872],
       [-1.72507889, -1.70618793, -1.68895362, ...,  1.68897011,
         1.70620441,  1.72343872],
       [-1.72507889, -1.70618793, -1.68895362, ...,  1.68897011,
         1.70620441,  1.72343872]])
```

The values of each row is the same hence values on row 1 is the same as that of row 20.

when I run:

```
x_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
x = x_scaler.fit_transform(x)

I get:

array([[ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  1., -1.],
       ...,
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  1., -1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  1., -1.]])
```

On the other hand, if I use the standard formula:

```
x_max = np.max(x)
x_min = np.min(x)
x = 2*((x-x_min)/(x_max-x_min)-0.5)

I get:

array([[-1.        , -0.98904401, -0.97904881, ...,  0.98000961,
         0.9900048 ,  1.        ],
       [-1.        , -0.98904401, -0.97904881, ...,  0.98000961,
         0.9900048 ,  1.        ],
       [-1.        , -0.98904401, -0.97904881, ...,  0.98000961,
         0.9900048 ,  1.        ],
       ...,
       [-1.        , -0.98904401, -0.97904881, ...,  0.98000961,
         0.9900048 ,  1.        ],
       [-1.        , -0.98904401, -0.97904881, ...,  0.98000961,
         0.9900048 ,  1.        ],
       [-1.        , -0.98904401, -0.97904881, ...,  0.98000961,
         0.9900048 ,  1.        ]])
```

Why is this so? Is there some bugs or am I doing it wrongly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your data is being iterated over the wrong axis.

```
x_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
x = x_scaler.fit_transform(x.T).T
```

should give you the values you expect

Comment: Thanks Riet, it works. But then I tried it on another data array:

    p_max = np.max(p)
    p_min = np.min(p)
    pn = 2*((p-p_min)/(p_max-p_min)-0.5)

    p_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
    p1 = p_scaler.fit_transform(p)
    pn2 = p_scaler.fit_transform(p.T).T

The results I got are different for pn and pn2. Shouldn't pn and pn2 be the same?

Comment: Not necessarily. `p_max` refers to the maximum over the entire data set (similar for `p_min`), while `sklearn` specifically searches only the first (0th) axis for a per-row maximum and minimum, which is where your first error came in. Working on data with identical rows should yield the same result (plus or minus machine precision).